# MySQL replication unsafe UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, replication

I have an SQL query like

```
UPDATE table SET foo = 'bar' WHERE pkey = n
```

Where
`pkey` is primary key, and `n` is integer constant.
Since i've turned binary logging on (in statement mode), mysql error log is full of warnings:

```
Statement may not be safe to log in statement format.
```

What could be causing this? As you can see, the statement has no ambiguity.

Also i have trigger `AFTER UPDATE` on this table. Whether the trigger be causing warnings?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-formats.html

Comment: I'm not able to use row-based/mixed replication because i need triggers to be executed on slave too.